# iPhone calendar app's Time Zone Override setting. Can I read it?

Tags: ios, iphone, calendar, eventkit

I am making a calendar app and want to support Time Zone Override. I know how to do it manually, but I'm wondering if there's any way I can get the setting user has chosen for iOS calendar app's Time Zone Override because I simply want to use the same setting.

Comment: Do anyone have answer for this question?